# What exactly is a metatype in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am very confused around the concept of "metatype" in the Swift language.

Suppose I have:

```
class SomeClass {
    class func callClassMethod() {
        print("I'm a class method. I belong to my type.")
    }

    func callInstanceMethod() {
        print("I'm an instance method. I belong to my type instance.")
    }
}
```

According to the definition:

> A metatype type refers to the type of any type, including class types,
>   structure types, enumeration types, and protocol types.

**SomeClass is already a type called SomeClass, then what exactly is the type of SomeClass?**

I can create a SomeClass.Type variable:

```
let var1 : SomeClass.Type = SomeClass.self
var1.doIt();//"I'm a class method. I belong to my type."
```

but I can also call the static/class function this way:

```
SomeClass.doIt();//"I'm a class method. I belong to my type."
```

**Are they the same?**

Comment: Metatypes are to my understanding the ones you have listed, class, struct, enum, protocol. `struct Example {...}` means `Example` is the type and `struct` the metatype

Answer (score 1):

They are the same because the compiler guarantees that class names are unique (Swift is name spaced by module), so there is only one thing that is of `SomeClass.Type` and that is the class `SomeClass`.  The meta type is often useful when you just want to pass the type of something to a function but you don't want to pass an instance.  `Codable` does this for instance:

```
let decoded = try decoder.decode(SomeType.self, from: data)
```

If you could not pass the meta type here then the compiler could still infer the return type based on an annotation on the left, but it would be less readable:

```
let decoded: Sometype = try decoder.decode(data)
```

Some libraries do use the type inference style instead, although the Apple preference seems to be to use the meta type as its clearer what the right side of the assignment is on its own, without relying on type inference from the left side of the assignment.